# pygtk import gtk error

Tags: windows, pygtk, importerror

I downloaded everything described as in  [pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/)  for installation. Everything went fine until when I tried to type `"import gtk"`, it threw an `ImportError` as follows:

```
from gtk import _gtk  
ImportError: DLL load failed: ...(something unreadable)
```

Then I re-install the pygtk-2.22.0 again, the same problem existed. So what to do please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operating system are you using? How did you install pygtk? Can you copy+paste the "unreadable" error message. It could be that someone here is awesome enough to be able to read it and figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Mark Byers, I am using a Japanese VISTA system, that message was really merely for god read, trust me, could you please figure out a solution? I install by double clicking the pygtk*.exe and everything moved as it is supposed to. thanks

Comment: The pygtk 2.22 binaries for Windows are only two weeks old, maybe there's a problem with it. I'm using the "old & stable" binaries (2.16) and everything works fine. An unreadable DLL name might mean that "_gtk.pyd" is corrupt.

Comment: I had the same problem with pygtk-2.24 (all in one package) on Python 2.7 32 bit on Windows. Funnily it didn't occur when I put "import gtk" in the main python file but only when it was in a subsequently called python file (probably because once the import worked a module is not imported twice). However this doesn't explain why it works one way but not the other. To summarize: The problem is still there however it can be even stranger than described in any solution here.

Answer (score 2):

The error you describe is usually caused by the python bindings (pygtk/pygobject/pycairo) being unable to load a dll it needs to function properly. Most of those errors are either caused by:

- the GTK+ runtime not being on your PATH environment variable. This has long been
  the advice on how to get pygtk working on Windows. Please don't change your user
  or system PATH environment variable, it is no longer needed with the all-in-one
  installer.
- multiple GTK+ runtime versions are on your PATH environment variable and the first
  (leftmost) one is not compatible with the pygtk/pygobject/pycairo versions you use.
  This is why adding the GTK+ runtime to your PATH environment variable is a bad idea:
  it is easy to mix up versions (sometimes GTK+ related installers add their bin
  directory to PATH on installation which contains an older or incomplete runtime).
- a rare case where some software package installed libintl.dll and iconv.dll into
  %WINDIR%\system or %WINDIR%\sytem32

The most straightforward way to avoid the dll hell described above is to use the
PyGTK All-in-one installer (http://download.gnome.org/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/).
It contains both the Python bindings, the GTK+ runtime and even Glade and does
no longer require you to change the PATH environment variable.

Small warning: if you decide to use the all-in-one installer, you'll have to uninstall
the separate pygtk/pygobject/pycairo packages you've used before (or you'll be in
a world of trouble...)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the conflicting initl.dll and iconv.dll problem. Take comfort in knowing that you help has been instrumental in delaying the inevitable breakdown of my sanity by a few more days.

Answer (score 0):

read the source code, perhaps there is a need for a specific version of pygtk

edit the source code to work with your pygtk version

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for the answer, I have actually checked with the versions and make sure that they are compatible. So that basically could not be a big problem, was it??

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. You didn't mention for sure in your answer, so I'll suggest the obvious (well...the obvious to people that have used it a while, perhaps). Did you use the following three lines of code to import? You have to use these, in order, to import PyGTK.

I'm assuming your version here is 2.24 like mine. If not, change it to the version you have.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.24')
import gtk
```

That should suffice in importing gtk.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

As others have noted, don't put gtk in the path. I know, its tempting, and it works for XYZ, but it (to say the least) gets confusing. Dependency hell is bad enough on a platform like Linux which tries to make it easy for you.

For clarification, what the PyGTK All In One does for you is to install (what appears to be) a full gtk+ runtime directly in your python packages folder, so e.g. in C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\runtime

## Solution

**NOTE**: %YOURPYTHONPATH% is an *EXAMPLE* variable which contains the path of your Python installation (e.g. C:\Python, or C:\Python27, or whatever it actually is). I suggest setting %PYTHON_DIR% or %PYTHON_PATH% if you want to use a variable to do this, as more programs are likely to use this.

To get your XYZ program requiring GTK to work, add **%YOURPYTHONPATH%**\Lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\runtime\bin to the PATH when running your program; the correct versions of the DLLs it needs to link against are in that folder. All other GTK+ runtimes I had installed (GTK+/GTK2-Runetime) gave me errors.

Again; **Do *not* attempt to set a user or system level variable (don't open up the dialog pictured below) as this will likely cause problems for you later unless you VERY sure you know what you are doing. If you are reading this, you most likely don't know as much as you think you do. Instead, alter the path in a cmd prompt, or use a batch/script file to set it up for you.**

[image: enter Windows Environment Variables Dialog]

Answer (score -1):

After you install the pygtk.org package, install each of these in the following order:

- pycairo-1.8.6.win32-py2.6.exe
- pygobject-2.20.0.win32-py2.6.exe
- pygtk-2.16.0+glade.win32-py2.6.exe
- gtk+-bundle_2.16.6-20100912_win32.zip

For more information:

http://freetstar.com/windows7-pygtk-gtk/

I got the secusses according the link on my PC.