# gedit-win32 plugin advancedfind load error

Tags: python, gedit

advancedfind is really a good plugin to analyze text files. It runs perfectly in Linux.

https://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/

However, when put in gedit-win32, it can't work because of following load error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GeditPortable\App\gedit\lib\gedit-2\plugins\advancedfind\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from advancedfind import AdvancedFindWindowHelper
  File "C:\GeditPortable\App\gedit\lib\gedit-2\plugins\advancedfind\advancedfind.py", line 27, in <module>
    import gtk.glade
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

** (gedit.exe:7508): WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'Advanced Find/Replace'
```

Can anyone help make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a result of either not having GTK for Windows installed/set up correctly, or a problem with the python bindings.  You can get Glade/GTK+ for Windows at http://sourceforge.net/projects/gladewin32/; if it's a binding issue look at the answers given here: [pygtk import gtk error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179425/pygtk-import-gtk-error)

Comment: Still failed after install python-2.6.6 and pygtk-all-in-one-2.22.5. Gedit should has internal mechanism to load/run python scripts (I see many python dll in gedit directory). import gtk works but gtk.glade fails.